# Why noble gas are not condensed? How inert gases get bonded?

Tags: solid-state-physics, inert-gases

Why are noble gas or inert gases not condensed? How do inert gases get bonded?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that "inert" does not mean "no electrostatic forces."  There's an interesting set of forces known as [Van der Waals forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force) which are dominant in noble gasses.  They include interesting effects like induced dipoles.  If you bring two neutral atoms close to one another, the electrons will move around to a lower energy configuration.  This lets the electrons of one atom be more attracted to the protons of the other than repelled by the other's electrons.  The electrons will move further away, and electrostatic forces are weaker at longer distances.

Most noble gases are kept in the gas state by thermal energy.  The random movement of the gasses keeps them from eventually condensing.  Cool them down enough, and we start to need to talk about condensed matter.  But that's another story entirely.

Comment: What are vander wal’s forces and vanderwals bonding and tell us about their origin?

Comment: @RickAndy Can you let me know what part of that is not covered in the linked Wikipedia article, so that I can better focus my reply?